# I have created models and my views function to add the attendance of employee. But data is not saving in database and no error comes up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a form named as `AttendanceForm` :

```
class AttendanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = '__all__'
```

These are models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    eid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=1)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    pincode = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name + ' ' + self.user.last_name


class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    attendancedate = models.DateField()
    in_time = models.TimeField()
    out_time = models.TimeField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)
```

view for attendance.

```
@csrf_exempt
def addattendance(request):
    form = AttendanceForm()
    emp_list = Employee.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AttendanceForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('employee/detail_attendance')

    return render(request, 'employee/addattendance.html', {'form': form, 'emp_list': emp_list})
```

I tried everything, but I don't know why the data is not saving into the database. Also, models are created fine, and the main thing is that there are no errors coming up. 
Please let me know if any changes are required.

Comment: Is your form valid?, try to print `form.is_valid()` inside this condition `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: i checked by print(form.is_valid()) its showing false . what to do

Comment: Means your form Is invalid if you print `form.errors` you can see which field is not valid or you can display error of each field in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest simple solution with Class-Based-Views:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

def AddAttendanceFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AttendanceForm
    extra_context = {"emp_list": Employee.objects.all()}
    success_url = reverse_lazy('employee/detail_attendance')
    template_name = 'employee/addattendance.html'

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Remember, that in urls.py you need to use `.as_view()` for class based views, like:

```
path((...), AddAttendanceFormView.as_view())
```

Also, you will not need `@csrf_exempt`, just put `{% csrf_token %}` anywhere inside your form's template.

Comment: it's not solution @NixonSparrow  give answer accordingly to questioner's question this portal is not for answering as you like

please understand questioner's rquirements

Comment: @Mahammadhusainkadiwala of course it's a solution. It fixes lack of error feedback from form which is the main problem in question, isn't it?